# Cloud Code Error - This user is not allowed to perform the get operation on _User

Tags: parse-platform

I am using the master key but still see this error.

> Error: This user is not allowed to perform the get operation on _User. You can change this setting in the Data Browser. (Code: 119, Version: 1.2.19)

This also seems to break a lot of other stuff like registration. I just want to make sure users can only change or set their username to something that does NOT start with a number and is alphanumeric. (compliant with channel names)

```
function usernameIsValid(username) {
    if (isNaN(parseInt(username[0])) && username.match(/^[a-z0-9]+$/i)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    if (usernameIsValid(request.object.get("username"))) {
        response.success();
    } else {
        response.error();
    }
});
```

Comment: This error is probably occurring before the beforeSave... What are your permissions set-up for the User class?  The master key wouldn't come in to play here, you're not querying or saving, just allowing or rejecting.

Comment: @Fosco There is quite obviously no get-permission for the User class (as the error says). Mr. Rodgers failed to ask a question, but I understand that he would like to ask why such a permission is needed here and how the beforeSave can be done without setting it.